# await for con metodo que devuelve promesa. El for no espera y se ejecuta inmediatamente. Vue, vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

La promesa que espera el dispatch('sendEmailLoop',noticeByLoop). La espera con exito. Lo que no logro hacer que espere es el ciclo for await(). Se ejecuta de inmediato sin esperar la promesa de abajo. Queria saber de que manera podria indicarle que espere esa promesa para que recien ahi siga recorriendo el array.
Lo otro que me pasa es que al devolver la promresa  dispatch('sendEmailLoop',noticeByLoop). A la primera  vuelta espera todo bien, despues las vueltas restante no las espera y las trae inmediatamente.
Estoy trabajando con vuex de vue.
SendEmailLoop, enviar una peticion a un controlador en php que envia email.
Para motivo de ejemplo devuelvo una promesa generica.

async setNoticeLoop({commit,dispatch,state},notice){

```
        for await (let email of notice.arrayEmail ){
             var hoy = new Date();
             var getMinutos = hoy.getMinutes();
             var getSegundos = hoy.getSeconds()
             var getHora = hoy.getHours()
    
             if(getMinutos<10){
                 getMinutos = '0' + hoy.getMinutes()
             }
             if(getSegundos<10){
                 getSegundos = '0' + hoy.getSeconds()
             }
             if(getHora<10){
             getHora = '0' + hoy.getHours()
             }
        
         var created_at = hoy.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" +(hoy.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
         ("0" + hoy.getDate()).slice(-2)+ ' ' + getHora + ':' + getMinutos + ':' + getSegundos;

             var setNotice = new FormData();
                 setNotice.append('aviso',notice.aviso)
                 setNotice.append('contacto',email)
                 setNotice.append('country',notice.country)
                 setNotice.append('created_at',created_at)
                 setNotice.append('order',notice.order)
                 setNotice.append('id_user',notice.id_user)
                 setNotice.append('identificacion',notice.identificacion)
                 setNotice.append('lat',notice.lat)
                 setNotice.append('lng',notice.lng)
                 setNotice.append('medio',notice.medio)
                 setNotice.append('metodo',notice.metodo)
                 
                await axios.post(API_BASE_URL+'controllers/noticeController.php?notice='+notice.metodo,setNotice)
                     .then(response =>{
                 if(!response.data[0].result){

                     console.log(response)

                     alertNegative("Ocurrio un error al registrar aviso")
                     commit('setLoadingSendNotice',false)
                 } else{

                      if(notice.medio === 'email'){
                          
                         const noticeByLoop = {
                         aviso : notice.aviso,
                         contacto : email,
                         country : notice.country,
                         created_at : notice.created_at,
                         order : notice.order,
                         identificacion : notice.identificacion,
                         medio : notice.medio,
                         metodo : notice.metodo,
                         locate : state.dataContacto.locate,
                         nameCustomer : state.dataContacto.nameCustomer,
                         }   
                             console.log("fun " + email)
                            dispatch('sendEmailLoop',noticeByLoop)  
                                 .then(res => {
                                         console.log(state.flagSendEmailLoop)
                                 })
                                 .catch(err =>{
                                     console.log(err)
                                 })
                     }

                  //si el aviso es desde el panel recolector / domicilio                    
                  if(notice.aviso === 'domicilio'){

                      if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('aviso') === null)){
                          const aviso = {
                              identificacion : notice.identificacion
                          }
                        localStorage.setItem('aviso',JSON.stringify(aviso))
                      }
                  }
              }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                commit('setLoadingSendNotice',false)
                console.log(error)
                alert(error)
            })
       
        
        }
        
    }
    ,async sendEmailLoop({commit,dispatch,state},notice){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              commit('setFlagSendEmailLoop',true)

              resolve()
            }, 3000)
          })
        
    },
```

esta es el console.log()

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El await se utiliza en funciones asíncronas para esperar la ejecución de una función externa, no puedes usar el await en un for. Tendrías que poner el await donde se deba esperar a una funcón asíncrona

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) para entender mejor el comportamiento async - await

Comment: El uso de [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) es completamente válido, sin embargo para que funcione debes iterar sobre un generador (puede ser un objeto o una función), y al parecer lo estás haciendo en una propiedad.